# Structure reference via character string

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

I am trying to understand basics of structure in C 
Please understand 
Here is my code :
I run code Blocks on Windows 7

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct xx
{
    int a;
    char x[10];
};

int main()
{


struct xx *p;
p->a=77;

    p->x[10] = "hello";
        printf("\n %d",p->a);
                  printf("\n %s ",p->x);
return 0;
    }
```

In the line where I try to do  print p->x
The program crashes 
!
Second Problem :
Is it true that When I do Not Initialize any structure integers they are by default zero 
AND strings non initialized (char star) are null by default if inside structure 
Third Question :
I have tried changing the line to

```
 p->x= "hello";
```

I get error even then !!
I have even tried to change

```
 char tem[] = "hello";

  p->x[]= tem[];
```

Still I get error

```
p->x= tem[];
```

This line also gives error 
even this

```
 char *tmp = "hello";

  p->x= tem[];
```

even this

```
 char *tmp = "hello";

  p->x[]= tem[];
```

even this line is error

```
 char *tmp = "hello";

  p->x[10]= tem[];
```

You may close this question but please clarify me !
How to initialize a character array in structure

Answer (score 2):

You must allocate memory for your `struct`, before you try to use it, by using [`malloc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html):

```
struct xx *p = NULL;
p = malloc(sizeof(struct xx));
if (!p) { 
    fprintf(stderr, "could not allocate memory for pointer p\n");
    exit(-1);
}
p->a = 77;
...
free(p); /* do this when you no longer need pointer p */
```

As far as accessing `x`, it's best to copy the string, *e.g.*:

```
#include <string.h>
...
if (strncpy(p->x, "blahblah", 4))
    fprintf(stdout, "p->x: %s\n", p->x); /* p->x: blah */
else {
    fprintf(stderr, "could not copy string to p->x\n");
    exit(-1);
}
```

Try using [`strncpy()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncpy.html) where you can, as manually specifying the number of characters can help enforce a habit of checking bounds, helping to avoid overflows.

For example, let's try to copy a `const char *` to `p->x`, which happens to be longer than what `p->x` can hold:

```
#include <assert.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 10

struct xx {
    int a;
    char x[MAX_LENGTH];
};
...
const char *foo = "blahblahblah";
assert(strlen(foo) < MAX_LENGTH); /* code should fail here */
if (strncpy(p->x, foo, strlen(foo) + 1))
    ...
```

When you run this, the `assert()` should trip:

```
Assertion failed: (strlen(foo) < MAX_LENGTH), function main, file test.c, line xyz.
Abort trap: 6
```

Once `foo` is shortened to nine or fewer characters (you need that tenth character for a `\0` terminator, remember!) the code should run properly.

So use `strncpy()` and check your bounds!

Comment: What does "inter access" mean?

Comment: @Rahul: The pointer variable p contains random garbage, so if you are "lucky" it points to some actual memory, somewhere. In that case, you can follow the pointer to that place, and put the number 77 there.

Comment: Your compiler may be doing something so that you get a garbage reference that you can still use. But on my end, when I write and run a test program without a `malloc()` call, I get a segmentation fault. So undefined actions result in unpredictable behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that the pointer **p**, which is supposed to point to a struct in memory, doesn't point to a struct. The pointer **p** just contains random garbage, and you have no struct for it to point to.

The simplest way to fix this is to create a struct variable, and let **p** point to it:

```
struct xx the_actual_struct;
struct xx *p = &the_actual_struct;
```

Also, you can't assign a string, such as the field **x** in the struct, with the normal assignment operator **=**. You need to use **strcpy**:

```
strcpy(p->x, "hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems;

1) You're confusing a pointer to a structure with an actual "instance" of a structure. p is a pointer, but it does not point to anything, you need to do a

```
p = malloc(sizeof(struct xx));
```

on the line after declaring it to make it point to actual allocated memory. You should use `free()` on that memory once you've finished using it.

An alternative would be to make p an actual struct instead of a pointer, changing it to

```
struct xx p;
```

(note the missing *) will make p an actual struct and you access the members using p.x (structure access) instead of p->x (pointer access). It is also (in contrast to memory you allocate with malloc) allocated locally for your function and will automatically "disappear" once it goes out of scope when your function exists.

Also, strings in C are also pointers, so assigning "hello" to something won't automatically copy the string. You need to use `strcpy(p->x, "hello");` to copy the data to your char array.

Lastly, no, almost nothing will be zeroed out in C automatically. Assume that you have to initialize *everything* and you'll be safe and don't have to remember what's done automatically and not.